# Add a 'local' variable to a shiny app

Tags: r

I have a shiny app using a regression model. The point is for someone to into my app and change some input variables to get a prediction using the regression model. What I'm doing now is pushing the dataset along the app into shiny, but the server needs to calculate the regression every time a variable changes, so it's very slow. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps calculating the regression on my computer before pushing the app would help, but I don't know how to add this variable to the app. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Any code you put outside the shinyServer() function is called only once on server startup and shared across all user sessions.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html explains scoping rules of shiny apps.

You might even be able to precaculate your regression model on your computer and store via saveRDS(), then use readRDS() on the shiny server to load the model.

Here's an example from the article above.

```
# A read-only data set that will load once, when Shiny starts, and will be
# available to each user session
bigDataSet <- read.csv('bigdata.csv')

# A non-reactive function that will be available to each user session
utilityFunction <- function(x) {
  # Function code here
  # ...
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # Server code here
  # ...
})
```